# UIPickerView selected audio file - App crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipickerview

OK. I have been working on an iOS project that I am trying to push to a more advanced stage of development. This is a simple Voice recorder app has Record, Play and Stop functionality.
So in an attempt to better understand the fundamentals of building a program like this, I am going through the process of building several versions that succeed in getting the separate functions of the app to work.
My basic recorder App consists of a storyboard that contains the View controller, and has a UIPickerview connected to it and also 3 buttons: Record, Stop and Play.
I have a working version that records a piece of audio and plays it back once recording has been completed.
All the subsequent recordings (as .caf files) are then displayed in the UIPickerview as the array of audio.caf object files.
However, At the time, I can only play back the recording that has just been made and I eventually need to be able to playback any of the audio files that can be selected in the Pickerview.
This is because a new file is created every time the app is launched as all the code at this point resides in the viewDidLoad of the UIViewcontroller, and not yet being called as a separate class.
I have to get to build this out later
So, right now I am building a aditional test version that will play back any selected audio file from the Pickerview.
This test version is not including the record actions, only the playback selection.

I have so far been reasonably successful in figuring out some of the programing problems in building this project, but at the time I am hitting some obstacles, I’m sure largely due to my programming knowledge limitations.
So, in this test version I have 3 audio.caf files currently residing in a folder in my iOS project documents path. 
These are successfully displaying themselves as an array in the UIPicker.
I also built a version with the audio files as part of my MainBundle (in a folder called ‘sounds’) and frustratingly, I could NOT get them to show up in the UIPicker.
Anyway, I have a class called `-(void)playAudioFile:(NSString*)selectAudioFile` that has the url path if the audio files calls the method as a string called selectedAudioFile.
This is also delegated to play as audio using the MyPlayer delegate of AVAudioPlayer.
So, the PlayAudioFile is called when the file is selected in the UIPicker. 
It does not play but instead crashes with the error of:

> “Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL
>   initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'.

The nil string parameter being that there is nothing being found when the string is selected!?! I’m not sure.
also, I have plenty of logs to check if my audio and file path objects actually exist (and the seem to be called ok at build time)
The logs says everything is being created here.

There are other issues that I haven’t covered that still need fixing, but this is the thread problem that I need to resolve at this point.
My .m and .h files are posted below. Any suggestions are welcome.
richG

![Voice Recorder App screen] http://sd.uploads.im/2rsk0.png

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
UIPickerView *AudioPicker;
NSArray *audioFiles;
AVAudioPlayer *myPlayer;


}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *AudioPicker;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *audioFiles;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *dirPath;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *selectedSound;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *PathComponents;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *docDir;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *filePath;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *fileName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *myPlayer;

-(void)playAudioFile:(NSString*)selectAudioFile;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){

}

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize AudioPicker;
@synthesize myPlayer;
@synthesize audioFiles;
@synthesize selectedSound;
@synthesize PathComponents;
@synthesize docDir;
@synthesize filePath;
@synthesize fileName;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Testing with literal array list <---
//audio = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"audio1.caf",@"audio1.caf", nil];


NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
audioFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *pathComponents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                              NSDocumentDirectory,           NSUserDomainMask, YES);

if([pathComponents count] > 0) {
    NSString *docDir = [pathComponents objectAtIndex:0];

    NSError *error = nil;
    audioFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docDir error:&error];
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"Failed getting files with error: %@",[error description]);
    }
    NSLog(@"Files are in fact being created...");

    NSInteger count = [audioFiles count];

    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.caf",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:count]];
    NSLog(@"------> CCCCCCCCCCCounting here , %d",[pathComponents count]);

    NSString *filePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    if ([filemanager fileExistsAtPath:docDir isDirectory:nil])
        NSLog(@"File does exist<--!!, %@", filename);
    else
        NSLog(@"File not found");

    NSLog(@"----> recorderFileName: %@",filename);
    NSLog(@"----> recorderFilePath <------: %@",filePath);



    }
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

#pragma pickerview
// sets up the pickerView with number of components to display
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return 1;
}


// sets up the number of rows for the pickerView
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:            (NSInteger)component {
return [self.audioFiles count];
}

// sets up the pickerView with titles from Parse
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row    forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

return [self.audioFiles objectAtIndex:row];
NSLog(@"audio row %@", [self.audioFiles objectAtIndex:row]);
}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
selectedSound = [self.audioFiles objectAtIndex:row];
NSLog(@"selected sound %@",selectedSound);

NSLog(@"testing player %@",[self.audioFiles objectAtIndex:row]);
[self playAudioFile:selectedSound]; //<-- CAUSING CRASH WHEN A STRING IS SELECTED

}

-(void)playAudioFile:(NSString*)selectAudioFile{
//** --> UPDATE EDIT <---------------------------------------------------------------- **
/* --> This piece a code was used from working with a another tutorial 
// on getting an array for a UIPickerView.
// This method was using the Mainbundle to store the files, 
// but did not seem to work either with
// this approach or my project version that 
// is storing the files in the directory.
// This seems to be my problem here, in getting 
// a reliable way of creating a URL for the
// files in the ObjectAtIndex to be retrieved.
*/

// ADDED CODE HERE
NSRange range = [_selectedSound rangeOfString:@"."];
NSString *filename = [_selectedSound substringToIndex:NSMaxRange(range)-1];
NSString *fileExtension = [_selectedSound substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(range)];


NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:filename
                                     ofType:fileExtension]];
// ADDED CODE CONCLUDED! <---
//** END OF EDIT ***********************************************************************

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: filePath];
NSLog(@"URL is here <---- %@", url);
NSError *error;

myPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
            initWithContentsOfURL:url
            error:&error];
//myPlayer =  [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_filePath] error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
          [error localizedDescription]);
} else {

    myPlayer.delegate = self;
    [myPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [myPlayer play];
}
}
@end
```

Print out of NSLogs displaying in console before UIPicker is selected, then making the app crash.

```
2014-09-29 18:50:19.912 PickerWithDocumentsTest[1826:70b] Files are in fact being created...
2014-09-29 18:50:19.914 PickerWithDocumentsTest[1826:70b] ------> CCCCCCCCCCCounting here , 1
2014-09-29 18:50:19.916 PickerWithDocumentsTest[1826:70b] File does exist<--!!, 4.caf
2014-09-29 18:50:19.916 PickerWithDocumentsTest[1826:70b] ----> recorderFileName: 4.caf
2014-09-29 18:50:19.917 PickerWithDocumentsTest[1826:70b] ----> recorderFilePath <------: /Users/macbook/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/1A55457F-9D74-4E25-A546-2622C11EB7DB/Documents/4.caf
2014-09-29 18:50:22.359 PickerWithDocumentsTest[1826:70b] selected sound 1f.caf
2014-09-29 18:50:22.360 PickerWithDocumentsTest[1826:70b] testing player 1f.caf
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Again, when the App crashes, the error is:

```
'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '* -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'.
```

Comment: Once print the 'audioFiles' log and show it. And some code is missing for playAudiofile method

Comment: Ramesh- I edited my post with updated code that should really be there after all, please note the added code in the ViewController.m file with the comments preceding it. Then at the end is the print out from the console logs. let me know if this helps, and thanks for your time etc. -rg